# Is there a Telerik control that can open, edit, and export Visio files?

Tags: telerik, visio, telerik-reporting

Is there a Telerik control that can create, open, edit, and export Visio files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such Telerik control. Telerik "Diagram" control does not support Visio files, as of now.

If you just want *any* diagram in your application (not specifically a Visio diagram), then there is a wide choice of diagramming controls. But they just won't work with Visio diagrams.